# uploading a file and form Data in web Api and angularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am following a guide in this [blog](http://chris.59north.com/post/Uploading-files-using-ASPNET-Web-Api)  on how to post form Data and 
a file. I am trying to upload the file in a directory on the server
have done following but it is not working.

this is the Post function

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            String root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logo/");

            if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            var data = await Request.Content.ParseMultipartAsync();
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            if (data.Files.ContainsKey("file"))
            {

                var file = data.Files["file"].File;      // this is getting the file
                var fileName = data.Files["file"].Filename; // this is getting the fileName
               // System.Web.HttpPostedFile filePost = data.Files["file"];
                String a = root + "" + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                string b = a;
                var postedFile = fileName;                                                  // this is not working
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logo/" + fileName);    // can someone help please 
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);                                                // I

            }

            if (data.Fields.ContainsKey("description"))
            {
                var description = data.Fields["description"].Value;
            }

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Thank you for uploading the file...")
            };
        }
```

how can I save the file to the Directory on the server?

Answer (score 7):

currently I'm using the following code to upload image files, but it also work for any type of file:

```
public string UploadImage()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType)));
        }
        var context = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (context.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var resourcePhoto = new PhotoHelper(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"));
            var file = context.Files.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault();
            var result = resourcePhoto.SaveResourceImage(context.Files[file], User.Identity.Name);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And in the `SaveResourceImage` I do the following:

```
 postedFile.SaveAs(resultPath);
```

That`s it.

Answer (score 5):

**Service**

```
app.factory('myService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        uploadFile: function(url, file) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: file,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }, //this is important
                transformRequest: angular.identity //also important
            });
        },
        otherFunctionHere: function(url, stuff) {
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        fileInput.click();

        //do nothing if there's no files
        if(fileInput.files.length === 0) return;

        var file = fileInput.files[0];

        var payload = new FormData();
        payload.append("stuff", "some string");
        payload.append("file", file);

        //use the service to upload the file
        myService.uploadFile('/path/to/API', payload).then(function(response){
            //success, file uploaded
        }).catch(function(response){
            //bummer
        });
    }

}]);
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile(string stuff, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    //save the file
    try
    {
        file.SaveAs('somePath' + fileName + extension);
    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        return Json(new { status = 'error', message = exc.Message });
    }

    return Json('horray');
}
```

Comment: You saved my day! Ajax post will set correct content-type header for FormData only if you explicitly set Content-Type to undefined!

Comment: this only accepts one file, right? how could you modify this to accept multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adjust the code with this snippet and that does the trick

```
 var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];                                                 // this is not working
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logo/" + fileName);    // can someone help please 
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way on Angular 1.5. So I have controller and repository in front end.I didnt save it in local drive. But there is a buffer, which we can save wherever we want.

**Controller:**

```
function submit() {

        modelTemplateRepository.add(model.modelTemplate, model.file)
            .then(function(response) {
                if (response && response.status) {
                    if (response.status === 422) {
                        model.apiError = response.data;
                        model.isSubmitting = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        onSaved(response.data);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
function add(modelTemplate, file) {

        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('modelTemplate',angular.toJson(modelTemplate));

        return $http.post(config.ApiEndpoint + '/modeltemplate', fd,
        {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
            .then(addComplete)
            .catch(function(data) {
                return angular.fromJson(data);
            });

        function addComplete(response, status, headers, config) {
            return response;
        }
    }
```

**API:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/modeltemplate")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {

        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        var file = provider.Contents.First(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"file\"");

        var filename = "";
        var buffer = new byte[0];

        if (file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName != null)
        {
            filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
            buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        }

        var formContent = provider.Contents.First(x => x.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"modelTemplate\"");
        Task<string> stringContentsTask = formContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var stringContents = stringContentsTask.Result;
        var dto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringContents);

        var result = ApiHelper.Add<dynamic>("modeltemplate", dto);

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For saving file to Server, you can make use of **MultipartFormDataStreamProvider**. Also I don't think you need to pass in request as one of the parameter.

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
```

And then can get handle to file as

```
// Read the form data.
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // This illustrates how to get the file names.
        foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

[This page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) on ASP.NET give a good overview of how to do it..